# what is the best way to wrap different components with ids in react-native dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, android-espresso

I have few components in my react-native App. I want to wrap a component called "Tooltip" around these elements in react-native. What is the best way to do this in react-native.

For example

I have components like

```
<Text id="123">content</Text>
<View id="456" >.....</View>
```

I want to wrap these components and replace them in the virtual DOM by wrapping a tooltip

```
<Tooltip><Text id="123">content</Text></Tooltip>
<Tooltip><View id="456" >.....</View></Tooltip>
```

Any lead in this direction would be helpful !

Thanks!

Comment: I feel what u have done is the efficient way, are you facing any issues in this way? please mention

Comment: @VarunS I haven't done it yet. I was wondering if there were any packages or tools that might help me doing this. To achieve this I will have to search for that component based on an id and replace it. I am not sure how to replace it dynamically in the virtual DOM

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom wrapper that accepts any components

```
const CustomTooltip = (props={}) => {
const {children: ChildComponent, id} = props
  return (
    <Tooltip>
        <ChildComponent id={id} />
    </Tooltip>
  )
}
```

and use like this:

```
<CustomTooltip id="123"><Text>...</Text></CustomTooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tooltip.js**

```
const Tooltip = ({children})=> {
  return(
   <View>
       {children}
   </View>
   )
}
export { Tooltip }
```

Usage inside **App.js**

```
import { Tooltip } from './Tooltip'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Tooltip>
      <Text>Hello World</Text>
   </Tooltip>
  );
 }
```

**Bonus tip with fragments**

```
import { Tooltip } from './Tooltip'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
     <Tooltip>
       <Text>Hello World</Text>
     </Tooltip>
     <Tooltip>
       <View>
           <Text>Hello World 2</Text>
       </View>
    </Tooltip>
    </>
  );
 }
```